# Generate movie with some effects on server side like Facebook lookback

Tags: facebook, flash, server-side, mp4, movie

I want to create the system like facebook lookback, but I have no idea.

https://facebook.com/lookback/

It generate videos by some pictures with some effects.
Do you have any ideas that you can create something similar?
Create swf(Flash) and capture screen on server side?
Or are there something like useful library that make movie with effects?

Any advice is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Actually the movie was created for each Facebook user, it wasn't generated when a user visits "A lookback" page! .because some users reported that they visited the page but their movie wasn't there, but you can do with HTML5 canvas element or jQuery/CSS3 animation

Comment: Thanks! Actually, the movie preview on video edit page is by html5. 
But, on the preview page (https://www.facebook.com/lookback), it's mp4. 
I checked chrome://net-internals/#events and found out the mp4 file.
I want to know how I can convert html5 movie to mp4.
Do you have any ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: _"HTML5 to MP4"_ that impossible, I didn't see the "edit video page" yet I will have a look later

Comment: About the "Lookback edit page" it's create using _jQuery & CSS3 animation_ as I told you before _"you can do with HTML5 canvas element or jQuery/CSS3 animation"_

Comment: Thanks, Adam! I see I can do with HTML5 canvas element or jQuery/CSS3 animation.

Comment: I saw the animation of facebook lookback was created by HTML5 canvas.
Please, tell me how to make mp4 file as same animation as created by HTML5 canvas.  

Are they video-capturing HTML5 canvas animation automatically?  
Or image-capturing HTML5 canvas animation 30 images per second and combine them to 1 mp4 movie?

Comment: No, it's just **jQuery/CSS3 animation** not canvas! if you inspect the `div`s you will their `style` attribute are changing ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Stupeflix API to do server side video renderings, using After Effects templates or built-in effects : http://developer.stupeflix.com/documentation .

Comment: Wow!It's so nice!! Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at the new release of Templater for After Effects?  The [Templater Bot](http://dcly.io/templater-bot-aes) edition will give you the flexibility to integrate After Effects into your own server application.  It comes with a command line interface, too.